# Null Pointer Exception at Hibernate Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-security

I'm trying to execute an hibernate query I am using **JSF 2 Primefaces, Spring security 3 and Hibernate  4**. I have checked that hibernate communicates with the database because it is able to create the tables automatically when you start the program.

I've tried to get the current session and also creating a session at the time of executing the query but i don't know if this is the reason. I have searched and tried all possible solutions but I have not found one.
I always get the following error:

**ERROR**:

> com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Can not instantiate class: core.bean.HolasBean at at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:193)
>       at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
>       at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
>       at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116).....
>
> Caused by:java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at core.bean.HolasBean.(HolasBean.java:22)

The line 22 is the **query**:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
            "from Holas");
```

Testing with the simplest example possible:

**HolasBean**:

```
    @Named
@Scope("session")
public class HolasBean{


HolasBo holasBo;
HolasDao holasDao;

public void setUserBo(HolasBo holasBo) {
    this.holasBo = holasBo;
}

public String printMsgFromSpring() {          //This works

    return "HOla";

}
public String getMessage(){                  //Null pointer exception

    return holasDao.getMessageHiber();
}
```

**HolasDao**

```
@Repository
public class HolasDaoImpl implements HolasDao {

    @Autowired
     private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public String getMessageHiber() {
        List<Holas> holas = new ArrayList<Holas>();
        holas = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Holas").list();

        return holas.get(0).toString();
 }
}
```

**Model**: Holas.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "gm_holas")
public class Holas {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;


//getters and setters
}
```

**XHTML**

```
<h:body>

        <h1>JSF 2.0 + Spring Example</h1>

    #{holasBean.printMsgFromSpring()}  //This is working
    #{holasBean.getMessage()}          //Null Pointer Exception

    </h:body>
```

**EDIT **:

Sergey when I comment I get this error on the website:

> Property 'holas' not found in type core.bean.HolasBean

**Configuration files in case you need:**

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID"
     version="2.5">

<display-name>Project Name</display-name>

<!-- Spring Context Configuration' s Path definition -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
       /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- SPRING SECURITY -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring listener. It is registered to Servlet Container -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Project Stage Level -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Welcome Page -->

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- JSF Servlet  -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Mapping for the http requests. -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**aplicationConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http:...

<!-- SPRING SECURITY -->    

<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secured/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/index.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/malvamos" default-target-url="/aleadormir"/>
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/index"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userServiceImpl" />
</security:authentication-manager>


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<task:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="core" />



<!-- TRANSACTION MANAGERS -->

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>



<!-- DATA SOURCES -->

<bean   id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/connection.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${cnn.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${cnn.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${cnn.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${cnn.password}" />
</bean>




<!-- SESSION FACTORIES -->

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate-config.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>core.model.Permission</value>
            <value>core.model.Role</value>
            <value>core.model.UserEntity</value>
            <value>core.model.Holas</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                ${cnn.dialect}
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name> Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.1.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL Java Connector dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- c3p0 dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <finalName>gesmo</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Any help or comment is welcome!!

Comment: When you commented this line(22) you have no error?

Comment: Try debugging and put a breakpoint at line 22. This would allow you to see what is actually causing the exception, and lets you narrow down the problem.

Comment: I edited the post commenting the sentence, now I'll try to make debugging

Comment: I cant debbug i have tried but is a webapp maven project and i can't eclipse or trying debug remote webapp i cant.